# Window Alert for electron on main.js

Tags: javascript, electron

I am using electron to launch a url using win.loadURL("/").

I was wondering if I could make electron show an alert when the window is opened.
I am trying to let someone know something when they open said session using npm run

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
dialog.showErrorBox('Title', 'Prompt text')
```

This shows an ERROR (X) but works as needed.

Comment: Don't forget to import: `const { dialog } = require('electron')`